# Java jtable specific column with radio button

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to filter rows with a specific column when I search and click radio button.

```
  check = new JRadioButton("Name");
  String[] columnNames = {"Name", "Technology"};
  Object[][] rowData = {{"Raja", "Java"},{"Vineet", "Java Script"},{"Archana", "Python"},{"Krishna", "Scala"},{"Adithya", "AWS"},{"Jai", ".Net"}};
  jtf.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
     @Override
     public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        search(jtf.getText());
     }
     @Override
     public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        search(jtf.getText());
     }
     @Override
     public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        search(jtf.getText());
     }
     public void search(String str) {
        if (str.length() == 0) {
           sorter.setRowFilter(null);
        } else {
            sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(str));
        }
     }
  });

  check.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
      public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

          if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {

          } else if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {

          }
      }
  });
```

I am trying to display the Name column's values when clicking the radio button `"Name"` and searching on `jtextfield`.

I know `sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(str, 1));` will display with Technology column, but I want to keep it going with searching during the radio button is selected.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting). The working example shows how to filter on a given column.

Comment: Hmm thanks, but I don't still get it.

Comment: What don't you get? It is a working example. I guess we don't understand your question.